# Why does PHP recognize int 0 as the first case in a switch statement?

Tags: php

Why does the following code trigger the first case, instead of the one that actually matches.

```
switch (0) {
    case 'test':
        echo 1;
        break;
    case 0:
        echo 2;
}
```

result: 1

It seems to be something with 0. If i try `switch(1)` I get nothing, and `switch(2)` will trigger `case 0` which is expected.

This is in php 7 on both mac and debian.

Comment: Why are you doing `switch (0)` in the first place? But `switch` uses a loose-typed comparison, and `0` == `test` loose typed

Comment: That's example code. My actual code is more complicated than this, but I found it when my switch input happened to be a 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing an integer to a string. This can't be done, so PHP does an implicit type cast.

PHP picks the cast to integer and converts `'test'`.

And `(int)'test'` is `0`. Therefore the first statement matches.

This could get even weirder:

```
switch (1) {
  case '1test':
    // would also match
  break;
}
```

Comment: Ah, i guess I was confused by when it casts a string to a boolean where "test" is true and 0 is false. This makes sense. Thanks!